# How do I send a message directly to my app?

Tags: google-mirror-api

My app added a sharing contact and I enabled it. I can share a picture to my app, but I can't send a message to my app because the contact does not show up in the 'ok glass, send message to ...' list.

Is there some way to allow my app to be a 'real contact that I can send a message to? If not, what is the easiest way to send a message to my app?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you please add a little more details to your question? As it stands it may not get many views and may even get deleted given it's too vague with little support facts/information to help others try and answer it.

Answer (score 6):

## Current Options

### Through The API

You can create a timeline item and add a reply menu item to that timeline. You should be able to have your app fetch that timeline item after receiving a notification with the timeline ID. From that timeline ID you can fetch the attachments including the audio file and the transcription.

Here is an example of the body for the new timeline item:

```
{
 "text": "Hello world",
 "menuItems": [
   { "action": "REPLY" }]
}
```

To see an example response take a look at the [Timeline Reference](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline#resource) page.

### A More Creative Approach

What you could do is create [Twilio](http://twilio.com) account to create a number that you can txt message to. You could then have your application interact with the body of the text message.

Comment: Thanks. I know you can do that, but that is not what I want. I dont want to search for the timeline item (which ends up further and further back in time), just so that I can reply. Instead I want to send a message directly to the app using only a voice command.

Comment: I'll update my answer to let it be known that is not possible at the current time. EDIT: Updated with a solution outside the API.

Answer (score 5):

At this time, the Mirror API does not support this function.

There's a [pretty similar feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=6) in the issue tracker. I recommend you add your feedback there and star the issue so that you'll be notified when it is updated.